# How to reference two dataset in SAS

Tags: sas

I have two separate datasets `Data1` and `Data2`.  `Data1` contains a set of names.   `Data2` contains names that have changed (original and new name).  How can I use `Data2` to update `Data1` with the new names?

```
Data1:
Richard,
Tommy,
Apple,
John,

Data2:
(original:first column) Richard;
(current: second column) Big Richard

Target:
Big Richard,
Tommy,
Apple,
John,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're familiar with SQL-left join syntax, you can use the `coalesce()` function to achieve this.  It simply returns the first non-missing value.

Using @user667489's sample datasets:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table want as
  select coalesce(b.newname,a.name) as name
  from original a
  left join current b on b.name = a.name
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

A merge will do this quite easily provided that you don't have any duplicate names, e.g.

```
data original;
    input name $16.;
    cards;
Richard
Tommy
Apple
John
;
run;

data current;
    input name :$16. newname $16.;
    cards;
Richard Big Richard
;
run;

proc sort data=current;
    by name;
run;

proc sort data=original;
    by name;
run;

data new;
    merge original current(in=b);
    by name;
    if b then name=newname;
    drop newname;
run;
```

There are various other ways of doing this if you'd prefer to overwrite the original dataset directly - e.g. the `modify` data step statement or `proc sql` with an `insert` statement - but those have more fiddly syntax.